# Register metaprogramming class

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I'd like to use Python's meta-programming capability to create classes programmatically. I can see how `Foo` can be instantiated here

```
 Foo = type('Foo', (), {})
 foo = Foo()
```

but what if the call of `type` happens in a function? How can I get `Foo` to be registered in the same way as `class Foo(): pass` would have worked? I'd like to call `foo = Foo()` without maintaining a class variable `Foo`.

Comment: What do you mean? Registered where? What difference are you experiencing between `Foo = type('Foo', (), {})` and `class Foo: pass`? Both of them define the variable `Foo`.

Comment: What do you mean by calling `foo = Foo()` without maintaining the variable `Foo`? What do you want to achieve by doing so?

Comment: I have a list of class definitions and I'd like to create those classes, but I don't necessarily want to maintain the return value of `type` (`Foo = type(...)`) and use that to later instantiate a class. I would just like to call `foo = Foo()` from the current scope (just as if the class was defined in the standard way).

Comment: That's what [`global` keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) is for.

Answer (score 0):

As a global:

```
def def_Foo():
    global Foo
    Foo = type('Foo', (), {})

def_Foo()
foo = Foo()
```

As a part of a module:

```
import types

quux = types.ModuleType('quux')     # skip if you already have a module
def def_quux_class(name):
    setattr(quux, name, type(name, (), {}))

def_quux_class("Foo")
foo = quux.Foo()
```

To define an arbitrary top level class:

```
def def_class(name):
    globals()[name] = type(name, (), {})

def_class("Foo")
foo = Foo()
```

Comment: What if the name of the class `Foo` was stored in a variable (actually all parameters of `type` are stored as variables).

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get Foo to be registered in the same way as `class Foo(): pass` would have worked? I'd like to call foo = Foo() without maintaining a class variable Foo.

Well, short answer: you can't. Because, actually, what the `class` statement is doing is to call `type()` **and create a variable by the name of the class**. Quite simply, no "registration" nor black magic involved.

Now you can of course use one of Amadan's hacks to avoid *explicitely* defining this variable, but I really would not advise doing so, as it will only make your code harder to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do so, you can use `globals()`, which returns the dictionary of all global variables. But modifying globals directly is **NOT** recommended.

```
list_of_classes = [type('Foo', (), {'x': 1}), type('Bar', (), {'x': 2})]

for each_class in list_of_classes:
    globals()[each_class.__name__] = each_class

# Python shell
>>> Foo
__main__.Foo

>>> Bar
__main__.Bar
```

Again, please consider trying to find another way. In general, you don't need any metaclasses in most cases.